# How to xpath values in a dynamic table?

Tags: html, xpath

Could please someone help me to xpath values in a dynamic table.

I have the following HTML code and I need to select the values of the cells, as for example:

if a tr-cell contains the text "Values1" then select the first value (0) in td / third value (1) in td of this cell

I would be very thankful.

```
<table class="DynamicTable">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Values1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Values2</td>
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Values6</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `:nth-of-type()` is your friend + some javascript. Best way to select them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: I need something like this, but it doesn't work : //tr/td[normalize-space(text())="Values1"]/td[1]/text()

Comment: OK, omg, I got it by myself :D You can work with preceding-sibling:: and following-sibling:: like //tr/td[contains(.,'Values1')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]

Comment: or //tr/td[text()='Values1']/following-sibling::td